# why python process a sorted list cost more time than a unsorted list

Tags: python

Example:

```
import cProfile, random, copy
def foo(lIn): return [i*i for i in lIn]
lIn = [random.random() for i in range(1000000)]
lIn1 = copy.copy(lIn)
lIn2 = sorted(lIn1)
cProfile.run('foo(lIn)')
cProfile.run('foo(lIn2)')
```

Result:

3 function calls in 0.075 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.075    0.075 :1()
        1    0.070    0.070    0.070    0.070 test.py:716(foo)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

3 function calls in 0.143 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.143    0.143 :1()
        1    0.137    0.137    0.137    0.137 test.py:716(foo)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense

Comment: It doesn't really seem to have anything to do with the sort. You can do `random.shuffle(lIn1)` instead of the sort and `cProfile.run('foo(lIn1)')` and you'll get the same result.

Comment: What caused the processing time to double?

Comment: Maybe the first list is still in cache? And you are using `lIn`, not `lIn1` in the first test call.

Comment: [why-is-copying-a-shuffled-list-much-slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107442/why-is-copying-a-shuffled-list-much-slower)

Comment: Before the shuffle, when allocated in the heap, the adjacent index objects are adjacent in memory, and the memory hit rate is high when accessed; after shuffle, the object of the adjacent index of the new list is not in memory. Adjacent, the hit rate is very poor.

Comment: That sounds like either a good self-answer or a reason to close as duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

Not **really** an answer yet, but the comment margin is a bit too small for this.

As `random.shuffle()` would yield the same result, I decided to implement my own `shuffle` function and vary the amount of times I'd shuffle. (In the below example, it's the parameter to `xrange`, `300000`.

```
def my_shuffle(array):
    for _ in xrange(300000):
        rand1 = random.randint(0, 999999)
        rand2 = random.randint(0, 999999)
        array[rand1], array[rand2] = array[rand2], array[rand1]
```

The other code is pretty much unmodified:

```
import cProfile, random, copy
def foo(lIn): return [i*i for i in lIn]
lIn = [random.random()*100000 for i in range(1000000)]
lIn1 = copy.copy(lIn)
my_shuffle(lIn1)
cProfile.run('foo(lIn)')
cProfile.run('foo(lIn1)')
```

The results I got for the second `cProfile` depended on the number of times I shuffled:

10000 0.062

100000 0.082

200000 0.099

400000 0.122

800000 0.137

8000000 0.141

10000000 0.141

100000000 0.248

It looks like the more you mess an array up, the longer operations take, up to a certain point. (I don't know about the last result. It took so long that I did some light other stuff in the background and don't really want to retry.)