# Copy performance: list vs array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, copy

I was optimizing a piece of code and figured out that list copying (shallow) was the bottleneck.

Now I am curious: why is list copying so much slower than copying an `array` of 8-bytes? In my opinion there should be no difference. In both cases it should be just `memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(int64_t)*len(src))` since pointers are 8 bytes long. But apparently Python does more work than I expected. Is it somehow related to GC? Or is it possible that lists are implemented as linked lists?

```
import array
import numpy as np
import timeit


n = 100*1000
lst = [i for i in range(n)]
arr = array.array('q', lst)
nmp = np.array(arr, dtype=np.int64)

assert(arr.itemsize == 8)

n_iter = 100000
print('=== copy() ===')
print('List of int:', timeit.timeit(stmt='lst.copy()', setup='from __main__ import lst', number=n_iter))
print('Array of 8-bytes:', timeit.timeit(stmt='arr.__copy__()', setup='from __main__ import arr', number=n_iter))
print('Numpy array of int64:', timeit.timeit(stmt='nmp.copy()', setup='from __main__ import nmp', number=n_iter))
```

The results:

```
=== copy() ===
List of int: 27.434935861998383
Array of 8-bytes: 2.6839109230022586
Numpy array of int64: 2.69919407800262
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the list, it's not just about copying references to the objects. It's also increasing the reference counters inside the objects. Plus those aren't cache-friendly, since they're not nicely adjacent to each other because they're inside objects (along with other data of the objects) *and* those objects are *somewhere* on the heap. Also see [Why is copying a shuffled list much slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42107442/1672429) (you have the faster "unshuffled" case here, but the explanations there might still be useful).

Comment: What about numpy array?

Comment: @AndreasK. Usually NumPy arrays don't contain Python objects but for example raw 64-bit ints, as in the question. So they don't have this extra cost and get copied much faster, as shown in the question. Does that answer your question? Your profile looks like you know NumPy much better than me, so I'm not sure why/what you're asking :-)