# How can I use assignment operation in list comprehension in python and convert following iterative code into it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have written reverse list code with O(n/2) complexity but I want to know how can I implement this code into list comprehension to get an idea of assignment operation in list comprehension.

```
word = list("overflow")
length = len(word)
for i in range(length//2):
  word[i] , word[(length-1)-i] = word[(length-1)-i] , word[i]

print(word)
```

I did some researched related to my solution but i found **:=** this operator and tried but didn't work.

```
word = list("overflow")
length = len(word)
word = [ word[i],word[(length-1)-i] := word[(length-1)-i] ,word[i] for i in range(length//2) ]
print(word)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, you can. Assignment expressions need to be wrapped in parens. But you absolutely shouldn't in this case as it massively decreases the readability of this code.

Comment: "I have written reverse list code with O(n/2) complexity" O(N/2) is not a complexity, where one ignores constant factors. It is O(N)

Comment: @j1-lee you can't hard code an algorithm that handles inputs of varying sizes, and algorithmic complexity is all about how algorithms *scale*.

Comment: You shouldn't be using list comprehensions for *side effects*. List comprehensions are for expressing mapping/filtering operations on arbitrary iterables to *create a new list*, not modify an existing list by side-effects. It's a functional programming construct borrowed from Haskell...

Comment: List comprehensions are for generating lists, not modifying existing lists. If you want to modify a list, use a for loop, as that's what they're for.

Comment: To be clear, your code is just trying to reverse the list? What's wrong with just `my_list = my_list[::-1]`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's very slow.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode compared to what?  I think `reversed(my_list)` is a bit faster but not orders of magnitude.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga O(n/2) is a linear time complexity which is O(n) because in Big-O-Notation we neglect constant terms but in real case we can say O(n/2). I add this statement here because someone might be shared brute approach  like reverse iteration which we can easily done using list comprehension but here my motive is to get an idea of assignment operation that's why i shared other approach of reversing which is efficient and can't be undone with assignment operation.

Comment: @Mark [`my_list.reverse()`](https://tio.run/##PY/basMwDIbv/RS6KbZDOhYKYQT6JKOEjiqrIT4gy4M@fWrHXnSj06dfUnjx07vLV6BtW8hbYGPRMBgbPHHLhIjIKcAVpJRix@juHtk1LD7Tsqwo7GteTeQMFqcy9Itq@Oy6UWvRINUgLYqYWDzBDMZBhS96EpCtlKNfExvvSle2qQ/CP6SISsv@KOZ9LfqepvNwk1WjWOnVJ9S/XA/7Nz24ZH@QroM@6EDGsZKn8QEpgoQTKIYOBhx1f5xT8YrqbXsD) (see the "Output" section).

Comment: Yes @don'ttalkjustcode that's obviously faster because it doesn't allocate a new list and reverses in-place. I suppose that's appropriate given that this is what the OP is doing.

Comment: hey buddies! I know I can solve my problem with multiple methods but my motive is to get an idea how can I use assignment operation in list comprehension. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: @HassaanRaheem but that's an anti-pattern. List comprehensions are for creating *new* lists. You are mutating a list in place, so using a comprehension is not a good option. You end up allocating a list for no reason.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode `my_list.reverse()` is "faster" because all it does is to return an iterator. It is not until the iterator is iterated through that any actual work gets done.

Comment: @blhsing Not true. You're thinking of `reversed(my_list)`.

Comment: @blhsing no, it doesn't, it actually reverses a list in-place, and in CPython, it is using an algorithm very similar to the for-loop above, just implemented in C

Comment: @blhsing Or perhaps of `my_list.__reversed__()`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oops a brain fart moment of mine. I guess it's the difference between a dedicated C code for reversal compared to a general-purpose create-a-slice-first-and-then-create-a-list approach.

Comment: Buddies you all are suggesting different methods , i know about it in terms of readability and memory management my list comprehension code is not sufficient but i want to get an exposure of assignment operation in list comprehension ?

Comment: @blhsing I think `[::-1]` is mostly slower because it has to increase every element's reference counter. If you leave out the shuffling in my benchmark, `[::-1]` speeds up by factor 4.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode You might be right about ref count increases. But no, shuffling slows down the reversal only because the CPU would no longer be able to perform effective predictive branching. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array

Comment: @blhsing What branches do you imagine there?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oops you're right. I now believe that shuffling makes the reversal slower because it causes excessive cache misses.

Comment: @blhsing Yes. The cache misses for the reference counters. [Also see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42107442/16759116).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you shouldn't be using list comprehensions for side-effects. List comprehensions are for expressing *functional, mapping/filtering operations on arbitrary iterables to create a new list*.

Furthermore, assignment expressions [explicitly aren't allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements) to be used for item-assignment (`a[k] = b`), only simple assignment to a name (`a = b`). So you could just use a function to use the assignment statement:

```
In [1]: def _reverse_helper(word, i):
   ...:     length = len(word)
   ...:     word[i] , word[(length-1)-i] = word[(length-1)-i] , word[i]
   ...:

In [2]: word = list("overflow")
   ...:
```

Now, it doesn't make any sense to re-assign the result of your list comprehension to `word` again, because **you are using the list comprehension for side-effects**. So, doing something like this is the closest equivalent to your original implementation:

```
In [3]: [_reverse_helper(word, i) for i in range(len(word)//2)]
Out[3]: [None, None, None, None]

In [4]: word
Out[4]: ['w', 'o', 'l', 'f', 'r', 'e', 'v', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions are for generating lists, not modifying existing lists. If you want to modify a list, use a for loop, as that's what they're for.
you can do like this  bro

```
def Reverse(lst):
    return [ele for ele in reversed(lst)]
print(Reverse("overflow")
```

return

```
['w', 'o', 'l', 'f', 'r', 'e', 'v', 'o']
```

i think this  what you need

Comment: yh its wors @mark

Comment: Why not `list(reversed(lst))`? Why have the comprehension at all?

Answer (score 0):

This one actually comes pretty close ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcwxCoUwEATQPqdYrBIQFG1sPElIIRh1IeyG/eGLjVePxGA3wzwmXulgGqcoOZ8sK8wQ8Jd0w38vW@CzMSp42tNRFk@6IKNsDxsLICCBLLR7XVHXDeZdCrPo2hpudEVa/bX2A8Y5FQUp1eOcHw)):

```
[0 for i in range(length//2) for word[i], word[~i] in [(word[~i], word[i])]]
```

But as everybody already said, don't use a list comp for its side effects.